# How to compile Boost.Log standalone

Tags: c++, boost, boost-build, boost-log

After doing some research, partially on the Stack Overflow, I decided to try [Boost.Log](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost-log/) library by Andrey Semashev.

Unfortunately, to build the Boost.Log library [I have to place it in the Boost source tree](http://mytechnotebook.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/how-to-build-and-install-boost-log/) and compile as it was part of the Boost. It is a blocker for me, because I have already somewhat complicated building configuration. **I want to build Boost.Log standalone.**

I've found [interesting thread on Boost.Log forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost-log/forums/forum/710022/topic/3407655), but this method doesn't work for me.

Comment: Just take the whole Boost and unzip the tree into some arbitrary location, then build it --with-log . It won't affect your "complicated building configuration".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Boost.Log, I might suggest you consider cpplog: https://github.com/andrew-d/cpplog

It's a header only library which is based on Google's logging library.